# seems like there is a php script that runs on my wsl, but i don't know which

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, laravel

I have an app that I built (using laravel 8), and I run it using sail (docker).
the docker/app are located in my WSL2 ubuntu system.

For some reason (that is the question here ..), "something" is filling the application's log file that is located on `project/storage/logs/laravel.log`. (with the same error, as attached)
I say "something" because it is being updated even if the docker service is closed and no browser/known-app is trying to access the app.

(There is a local apache on the WSL, but it is not active)

How can I find out what is it?

```
The error:
[2023-04-07 01:31:56] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `categories`) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `categories`) at /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:759)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(898): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback()
#1 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(878): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection()
#2 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(722): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->handleQueryException()
#3 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(421): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run()
#4 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2630): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select()
#5 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2618): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->runSelect()
#6 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(3154): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\{closure}()
#7 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2619): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->onceWithColumns()
#8 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(698): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->get()
#9 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(682): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->getModels()
#10 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(568): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->get()
#11 /var/www/project/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php(32): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model::all()
#12 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(36): App\\Providers\\AppServiceProvider->boot()
#13 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Util.php(41): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#14 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\\Container\\Util::unwrapIfClosure()
#15 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod()
#16 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(651): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call()
#17 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(930): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call()
#18 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(911): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootProvider()
#19 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->Illuminate\\Foundation\\{closure}()
#20 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(912): array_walk()
#21 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php(17): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->boot()
#22 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(239): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\BootProviders->bootstrap()
#23 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith()
#24 /var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#25 Command line code(1): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#26 {main}
```

Comment: Running where? Your question I am sorry to say makes no sense. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: thanks @David - i've edited my question.

Comment: You still do not say what version of Ubuntu. WSL is a platform to run Ubuntu but you had to have installed some version of the OS.

Comment: Sorry, @David missed that one when updated. I use Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS